# Intermittent issue while persisting JSESSIONID into the Cookies

Tags: http, jsf, cookies, browser, jsessionid

I've got some issues with the cookie session (JSESSIONID), this is very intermittent issue and very few people facing this in same environment and domain.

We are JSF application and persisting application state at server side, while accessing application browser maintains cookie(with JSESSIONID) to maintain session; but there is problem in some cases, browser is creating cookie but unable to persists JSESSIONID into, causing JSF application reload everytime(considering fresh session request)

One more twist, if we hit the URL without domain(e.g. http://xxx/app/page.jsf) it does store the JSESSIONID into the cookie, unlikly with domain http://xxx.domain.com/app/page.jsf cookie doesn't store JSESSIONID.(I'm confused :( )

Though if we clear cookies and re-try hitting http://xxx.domain.com/app/page.jsf then it works for a while.

Is it a problem in browser or a new way to use this cookie? 
Or is it anything to do with CORS?

Browsers we faced this issues are: Chrome and Firefox.

Thank you for your replies.

Comment: I'd check what the cookies are on the network level. See if there are requests for mixed urls etc. See if you can find a pattern.

Comment: Most browser don't save cookies for domains without dots (localhost, xxx). I had a problem with cookies when I tried to strip the application path. ( http://xxx.domain.com/page.jsf ) I had to tell glassfish a cookie-path to not get 2! JSESSIONID.  In glassfish-web.xml
`<session-config>
  <cookie-properties>
   <property name='cookiePath' value='/'/>
  </cookie-properties>
 </session-config>`